# Can the OCR language be changed using the DriveApp with Google Apps Script and ocrLanguage parameter?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr, google-docs-api

Using Google Apps Script (GAS), I was looking at the following code to perform OCR on documents stored in a Google Drive folder.
[OCR images from google drive using Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840148/ocr-images-from-google-drive-using-google-app-script)

```
Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true})
```

According this documentation for the Drive API V3 - the OCR language can be altered using a BCP 47 language code in the

```
ocrLanguage parameter.
```

> You can improve the quality of the OCR algorithm by specifying the applicable BCP 47 language code in the ocrLanguage parameter.
> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#import_to_google_docs_types

I know the parameter can be added to this GAS DriveApp code.

```
 Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {ocr: true})
```

But the only language recognized is en-GB and not en-US. Shouldn't this work with any language?

Comment: I think `en` is for `en-US`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert#parameters), you change the langage you need to set the `ocrLanguage` parameter:

```
Drive.Files.insert(file, image, {
  ocr: true,
  ocrLanguage: "en"
})
```

Also note that the Drive Advanced service uses [Drive V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) and not Drive v3, which may have some differences in method use.